# Minimize difference of difference of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, binomial-coefficients

Let
$$ f_n(i) = \binom{n}{i} - \binom{n}{i-1}$$
Is there an expression in terms of $n$ for
$$\min_{1 \leq i \leq n/2} f_n(i)$$
I know $f_n(1)=n-1$ but this does not equal the minimum value for all $n$, for example $f_4(2) = 2$, but I'm hoping I can find something in terms of $n$.
Maybe
$$f_n(i) = \Big( 1 - \frac{2i}{n+1} \Big) \binom{n+1}{i}$$
is useful?

Comment: If this is a function of $n$ and $i$, why would its minimum value be in terms of $n,i$?

Comment: looking at Pascal's triangle you should have a good idea of where the minimum occurs

Comment: This is an interesting problem. The function $f(k;n)$ seems to follow a sort of cubic pattern with a maximum around $2n/3$. See a graph on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dhq2ujlwio)

Comment: The unique minimum occurs at $i=1$ for all $n\in \{1,2,\dots\}$, except when $n\in \{4,6\}$. When $n=4$, the minimum is at $i=2$, and when $n=6$, there is a tie for the minimum between $i=1$ and $i=3$.

Comment: Correction - *minimum* around $k=2n/3$.

Comment: Update: the guess $2n/3$ is actually pretty far off the mark. But, I think $n+\log(n)$ is very close - see my updated answer.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, why is that the case? This seems to be my desired answer but do you have a proof for that statement?

Answer (score 2):

Just as @K.defaoite, I thought that the problem was to maximize
$$f_n(k) = \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n}{k-1} \qquad \text{for} \qquad 1 \leq k \leq \frac n 2$$

So, as @K.defaoite did, I shall try to work the maximization.

Using the gamma function and differentiating, we have to find the solution of
$$\frac{k^2+(k-n-1)^2}{k (k-n-1) (2 k-n-1)}=\psi (-k+n+1)-\psi(k) $$ Writing the second order Taylor expansion of the above expression around $k=\frac n2$ we need to solve for $k$ the quadratic equation
$$a \left(k-\frac{n}{2}\right)^2+b \left(k-\frac{n}{2}\right)+c=0$$ where
$$a=-\frac{\left(n^2+2 n-2\right) \left(n^2 \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-4\right)}{n^2}$$
$$b=n-\frac{4}{n}+\frac{1}{2} (n+2) n \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-1\qquad \text{and} \qquad c=\frac {n(n+1)}{2}$$ Retain the smallest solution (this is only an *estimate*)
$$k\sim \frac {n} 2+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a}$$

For illustration, let $n=10^p$ and compare
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 3.8284441 &  3.7898465 \\
 2 & 45.474367 &  45.458418 \\
 3 & 484.68068 &  484.67544 \\
 4 & 4950.4975 &  4950.4958 \\
 5 & 49842.385 &  49842.385
\end{array}
\right)$$

For very large values of $n$, from the quadratic equation, the asymptotics would be
$$k\sim \frac {n+1} 2-\frac 12 \sqrt n \left(1+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{37}{24 n^2}+O\left (\frac {1} {n^{5/2}} \right) \right)$$

Using this result as base point for a new expansion of the equation to solve gives
$$k\sim \frac {n+1} 2-\frac 12 \sqrt n \left(1+\frac{5}{6 n}-\frac{41}{360 n^2}-\frac{1721}{3024 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

Used for $n=10$, this gives $k=3.7898002$

**Edit**

In view of the previous result, we can even do better : let $k=\frac{n+1-x\sqrt{n} }{2} $ which makes the equation to solve
$$2\frac{ n \left(n+2+x^2\right)+1}{x\sqrt{n}  \left((n+1)^2-n x^2\right)}=H_{\frac{1}{2} \left(n-1+x \sqrt{n}\right)}-H_{\frac{1}{2} \left(n-1-x \sqrt{n}\right)}$$

Expanded as series around $x=0$, we have to solve for $x$
$$2=\sum_{p=1}^\infty a_p x^{2p}$$ where the  coefficients are
$$a_p=4n^p\Bigg[\frac { \psi ^{(2 p-1)}\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} {4^p\, (2 p-1)! }-\frac {1}{(n+1)^{2 p} }\Bigg]$$

Now, using series reversion
$$k\sim \frac {n+1} 2-\frac   {\sqrt n}2 \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{a_k}{n^k}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)\right)$$ where the coefficients $a_k$ form the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{5}{6},-\frac{61}{360},-\frac{227}{5040},-\frac{23483}{1814400},\frac{44933951
   }{119750400},-\frac{3444044587}{130767436800}\right\}$$

Trying for $n=2^p$, the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0.524771687500380499473261 &  0.529176960274205650239913\\
 2 & 1.302651240758724990905955 &  1.302745705191306338073585 \\
 3 & 2.942329575624503533168965 &  2.942330978833762361174524 \\
 4 & 6.397178792509027687945137 &  6.397178809463434940801070 \\
 5 & 13.59838783848710969755951 &  13.59838783867800346779702 \\
 6 & 28.44808282869740112407188 &  28.44808282869951434549459 \\
 7 & 58.80637589759390516640941 &  58.80637589759392849270466 \\
 8 & 120.4739790389675902908572 &  120.4739790389675905483369 \\
 9 & 245.1678845786669264194795 &  245.1678845786669264223226 \\
 10 & 496.4869817528550288338029 &  496.4869817528550288338343 \\
 11 & 1001.863376796720752704879 &  1001.863376796720752704879 \\
 12 & 2016.493489906543937479655 &  2016.493489906543937479655 \\
 13 & 4051.240562558556105524810 &  4051.240562558556105524810 \\
 14 & 8128.496744832066025772882 &  8128.496744832066025772882 \\
 15 & 16293.98803024251845644220 &  16293.98803024251845644220 \\
 16 & 32640.49837240088319177524 &  32640.49837240088319177524 \\
 17 & 65355.47951312808588722713 &  65355.47951312808588722713 \\
 18 & 130816.4991861985478970517 &  130816.4991861985478970517 \\
 19 & 261782.4607525877391722967 &  261782.4607525877391722967 \\
 20 & 523776.4995930990372370715 &  523776.4995930990372370715
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Final point**

Concerning the maximum value, using the above, we have
$$\frac{2 }{\sqrt{ne} }\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\left(1-\frac{7}{12 n}+\frac{239}{480 n^2}-\frac{184189}{362880
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \right)$$

Used fo $n=100$, this gives a maximum value of $1.216794929\times 10^{28}$ while a rigorous optimization leads to
$1.216794935\times 10^{28}$.

Comment: I actually thought the problem was to minimize $f$ for $k\in [1,n]$. It turns out that there is some nice symmetry and that the maximum can be found by reflecting the minimum about $k=n/2$. This might imply that $k=n/2-\log(n)$ is a good approximation for the maximization problem.

Comment: @K.defaoite. I found funny coefficients for expansion.

Comment: Nice! I wasn't expecting something so neat as this. Also the Taylor expansion around $k=n/2$ gives surprisingly accurate results. I was not expecting this - I tried to use $\psi(z)\asymp \log(z-1)$ but I think your approach is better.

Comment: @K.defaoite. Your approximation is good and simple. What I think is that your started with approximations too early.

Comment: If I could give two upvotes I most certainly would. This is excellent work!

Answer (score 1):

**Just for clarification:** My goal here is to minimize $f(k;n)$ in the range $k\in[1,n]$. As it turns out, $f$ admits some nice symmetry about $n/2$ and we have the relation $k_{\max}=n-k_{\min}$. This is the connection between mine and Claude's answer.

Via some algebra we can write as
$$f(k;n)=\frac{n-2k+1}{k}C(n,k-1)$$
Which can be expressed in terms of the Gamma function as
$$f(k;n)=\frac{n-2k+1}{k}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(n-k+2)}$$
Letting $\psi$ be the digamma function,
$$\partial_k(f)(k;n)=-\Gamma(n+1)\frac{k(n-2k+1)\psi(k)+k(2k-n+1)\psi(n-k+2)+n+1}{k^2\Gamma(k)\Gamma(n-k+2)}$$
So we look for the nearest integers to roots $k$ of the equation
$$k(n-2k+1)\psi(k)+k(2k-n+1)\psi(n-k+2)+n+1=0$$
You can do this in Mathematica with the following code:

```
n=(* whatver positive integer you want *);
NSolve[{1 + n + k (1 - 2 k + n) PolyGamma[0, k] + 
     k (-1 + 2 k - n) PolyGamma[0, 2 - k + n] == 0 && k < n && 
   k > 0}, k, Reals]
```

**EDIT: Some more analysis**
Here is a plot (red dots) of where the minima are attained for $n\in[1,1000]$ :

[image]
The growth appears *almost* linear, but not quite. It should be of the form
$$k_{\min}(n)=n/2+ (?)$$
Where $(?)$ is some unknown correction factor. What exactly this factor is is anyone's guess.

However, the approximation $k_{\min}(n)=n/2+\log(n)$ appears to be surprisingly accurate:
[image]
I think if I try to go any further I will start getting overflow errors.

Let's return to the function we want to find the larger root of:
$$g(k,n)=k(n-2k+1)\psi(k)+k(2k-n+1)\psi(n-k+2)+n+1$$
We'll see if we can approximate roots of this function.

We can approximate the digamma function by
$$\psi(z)\approx \log(z-1)$$
Which is actually a surprisingly accurate approximation that gets better and better for larger $z$. So we can say approximately
$$g(k,n)\approx k(n-2k+1)\log(k-1)+k(2k-n+1)\log(n-k+1)+n+1$$
$$=(nk-2k^2+k)\log(k-1)+(2k^2-nk+k)\log(n-k+1)+n+1$$
Using laws of logarithms we can express this as
$$g(k,n)\approx k\left(n\log\left(\frac{k-1}{n-k+1}\right)+\log\left((k-1)(n-k+1)\right)\right)+2k^2\log\left(\frac{n-k+1}{k-1}\right)$$
Which, admittedly, is not much of an improvement. But, perhaps it will submit more readily to numerical algorithms.

Comment: Remark - It seems I completely missed OPs demand that $k<n/2$. In that case it appears the answer is almost always $k=1$ with a few exceptions. I think in this setting it is best to just compute the first few values and take the smallest one, since $f(k;n)$ starts to grow quite fast.

Comment: @K.defaoite Wow this is very impressive, thank you! I'm sorry for any confusion I may have caused. Anyways, you hinge upon something interesting in your comment: the answer is almost always $k=1$ with a few exceptions. Why is that?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Why would it be a stupid one? I see that maximizing is a interestin problem aswell, but I don't understand why minimizing would be stupid? Is it too trivial?

Comment: @CaptainG. I sincerely apologize and I shall delete my comment. As you say, the problem would be very trivial. In fact, minimizing is possible if $1 \leq k \leq n$ and not  $1 \leq k \leq n/2$. Again, I am sorry. The problem of maximization is very interesting. Merry Xmas !

Comment: @CaptainG The function $f$ starts to grow very quickly for $k=2,3,...$ up to the maximum that occurs roughly at $k=n/2-\log(n)$. So the successive differences $f(3;n)-f(2;n),...$ start getting very big. If we want to minimize in the range $k\in[1,n/2)$ we going to find the solution either at or very close to $1$.

Comment: Just for the fun, look at my last update ! Cheers :-)